# Why does EncryptedSharedPreferences throw a or InvalidProtocolBufferException?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to initialise retrieve my app's EncryptedSharedPreferences. I am finding that on one device (A Samsung Galaxy A52 running Android 11) the app crashes on launch due to an InvalidProtocolBufferException, with the call to `EncryptedSharedPreferences.create()` in the stacktrace. I cannot reproduce this on other devices, including a Samsung Galaxy A52 running Android 12.

```
    private var encryptedPrefs = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
        "keystoreFileName",
        MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC),
        this, // "this" is my main activity
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
    )
```

Here is the exception:

```
com.google.crypto.tink.shaded.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
```

There is also an earlier exception for the same function call, but logged as a warning.

```
android.security.KeyStoreException: Signature/MAC verification failed
```

What might cause this, and how should it be fixed?

Comment: Hey @Ogre have you got any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Similar exception in devices from Xiaomi and Realme. But this doesn't occur every time. When user uninstall an old build and install a new build for the same package.

Answer (score -3):

What version of encrypted shared preferences do you use?
use stable instead of alpha versions

Comment: Facing the same issue..using 1.1.0-alpha03

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."